# Is this a good way to implement let-with?

Tags: scheme, macros

I've implemented a `let-with` macro that takes an association list, keyed by symbols, that enables code to bind their corresponding values to local variables.

It's designed to have a similar effect to JavaScript's `with`, but without [`with`'s attendant problems](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/) (by making you explicitly list the variables to bind).

```lisp
(define-syntax let-with
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((let-with alist (key ...) expr ...)
     (let ((key (cond ((assq 'key alist) => cdr))) ...) expr ...))))
```

I'd love to hear of any improvements to `let-with`'s interface and/or implementation.

Example usage:

```lisp
(define alist '((first . "Jane")
                (last . "Doe")))
(let-with alist (first last)
  (string-append first " " last))    ; "Jane Doe"
```

Keys that don't exist in the incoming alist receive an undefined value; they do not fail to get bound, unlike JavaScript's `with`.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's `with` statement allows one to modify object members.  This may not be possible for certain types of values (such as strings) using the `let-with` macro as defined above.

---

One could generalize `let-with` to bind values from several association lists.  It could have the form:

```
(let-with
    ((alist0 (key00 key01 key02...))
     (alist1 (key10 key11 key12...)))
  expr0
  expr1
  ...)
```

Aside from being more general, the above form closely resembles the `let` form.  I prefer this over the simpler form, though I would understand if your taste and needs differ.

Here's my implementation of the general form--it uses two auxiliary macros, one to generate two lists (alists and their corresponding keys) and the other to emit the actual code (which looks almost exactly like your definition above):

```
(define-syntax let-with
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((let-with bindings . body)
     (gen-let-with bindings () () body))))

(define-syntax gen-let-with
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((gen-let-with () alists keys body)
     (emit-let-with-code alists keys body))
    ((gen-let-with ((alist (key)) . rest-bindings) alists keys body)
     (gen-let-with
      rest-bindings
      (alist . alists)
      (key . keys)
      body))
    ((gen-let-with ((alist (key . rest-keys)) . rest-bindings) alists keys body)
     (gen-let-with
      ((alist rest-keys) . rest-bindings)
      (alist . alists)
      (key . keys)
      body))))

(define-syntax emit-let-with-code
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((emit-let-with-code (alist ...) (key ...) (expr ...))
     (let ((key (cond ((assq 'key alist) => cdr))) ...) expr ...))))
```

Perhaps there is a simpler definition.  I haven't played with macros in a while. =)

---

Here are some examples:

```
(define alist '((first . "Jane") (middle . "Q") (last . "Doe")))
(define blist '((first . "John") (middle . "R") (last . "Lee")))
(define clist '((first . "Jose") (middle . "S") (last . "Paz")))
(define first '((title . "Ms") (suffix . "Esq")))

(let-with
    ()
  "Hello, world!")    ;    => "Hello, world!"

(let-with
    ((alist (first middle last)))
  (string-append first " " middle ". " last))    ;    => "Jane Q. Doe"

(let-with
    ((alist (first))
     (blist (middle last)))
  (string-append first " " middle ". " last))    ;    => "Jane R. Lee"

(let-with
    ((alist (first))
     (blist (middle))
     (clist (last)))
  (string-append first " " middle ". " last))    ;    => "Jane R. Paz"

(let-with
    ((first (title))
     (alist (first))
     (blist (middle))
     (clist (last))
     (first (suffix)))
  (string-append first " " middle ". " last))    ;    => "Jane R. Paz"

(let-with
    ((alist (first middle last)))
  (set! first "Rose")
  (string-append first " " middle ". " last))    ;    => "Rose Q. Doe"

(let-with
    ((alist (first middle last)))
  (string-append first " " middle ". " last))    ;    => "Jane Q. Doe"
```

Since `let-with` expands into a single `let`, the third-to-last example works.

The last two examples demonstrate the inability to modify a value in its corresponding association list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer---I haven't forgotten about you (I've read it the moment it was posted). I wanted to write a full response to that, with my ideas about how such an extended macro might be implemented, etc., but my free time is so very limited at the moment. :-(